# Advise on coding image and text to already deployed HTML pages...

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am here to ask a couple of questions if I may.
I understand that the CSS is for styling, I have some method which works to a degree i.e text changing but this seems to be limited.

I have about 600 html pages that have some exact content on the pages. 
I would have liked to be able to have a CSS or text doc which can be altered to change all html pages in one hit.

Though I am limited to html and css only, other options are not available to me.

I would one like to change blocks of text that is some volume, and images if possible, so I don't have to redo every page as it's very time consuming.

The other issue it needs to be cross browser compatible.

I know there are some great minds out there, I am willing to give any of them a go...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with. Give us a mockup of the sort of things you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to deliver a stylesheet to all the 600 pages without having to manually edit them to include the `<link>`?

Comment: CSS is compatible with all major web browsers. Bad news is (as the other commenters already pointed out) you will have to add the [`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourStyleSheetName.css">` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) to every page. After that, it's just a matter of changing the one stylesheet to update the styles on all the pages, but you'll have to first add the `<link>` tag to every page. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the css rule, `"content: <desiredTextOrAttribute>"`
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Suppose you want to be able to set the title on all 600 pages to Company X:

HTML:

`<div class="companyName"/>`

CSS:

```
.companyName:after {  
    content: "Company X"  
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onm30rdn/1/

Of course, you won't be able to dynamically change this, and I think Javascript would be a way better solution in general. But this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can make your own custom stylesheets with css, you might get some love from pseudo-elements, such as ::before and ::after.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Basic idea is that if you can select an html element reliably, you can make a virtual element next to it for the browser to display. The code below would append "hello" before the existing text.

```
HTML
<body>
<p class="foo">World</p>
</body>

CSS
.foo::before {
content:"Hello ";
}
```

Result

> Hello world